# Где целесообразно использовать сравнение через ===?

Tags: javascript

В условных операторах часто приходится использовать проверку на равенство.

Недавно стал задумыватся о том что повсеместное использование `==` может привести к непредвиденным результатам из за приведения типов.

С другой стороны использование `===` увеличивает размер скрипта на один лишний байт, а, так как такое сравнение используется очень часто, "правильные" сравнения могут сильно раздуть небольшой скрипт.

В итоге все таки вывел для себя правило: если сравнение должно принимать результаты приведения то `==`, в остальных случаях `===`.

А что думаете вы на этот счет?

Comment: Я думаю, что вам не нужно экономить на спичках и сэкономленная сотня байт не даст абсолютно никакого эффекта. Те же пробелы, отступы, комментарии и длинные имена переменных отнимают куда больше места, но вы же наверняка их используете? Если вам очень хочется экономить на спичках, лучше прикрутите к коду какой-нибудь минификатор, например uglifyjs с webpack.

Comment: Забавный факт: в (ненужном) CoffeeScript `==` разворачивается в JS в `===`.

Answer (score 1):

Так как при использовании `===` в случае операндов разных типов не осуществляется приведение их к одному общему, то использовать данный оператор нужно, если *требуется* чтобы операнды с разным типом были не равны.

Однако, при сравнении операндов с одинаковым типом разницы между `==` и `===` нет.

Таким образом, если гарантируется, что операнды будут иметь одинаковый тип, все равно какой из операторов будет использован.

Если не гарантируется, то стоит исходить из требований: нужно ли приводить к общему или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от типов сравниваемых операндов. Если уверен, что тип будет одинаковый то нет разницы, а с вашей точки зрения - лучше == . Если же, есть шанс, что тип будет разный, то смотрите на то, что к чему будет приводится и тогда используйте === только если уверены, что данные смогут правильно привестись к какому-то типу.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем нормальными словами `===` используй только если ты уверен что сравниваешь два значения с одинаковыми типами например строку со строкой:

```
'asd' ==== 'asd' // вернёт true.
```

А при использовании `==` типы приводяться к сравнимому значению например:

```
'1' == 1 // вернёт true, если бы было === вернуло бы false.
```

Comment: _если ты уверен что сравниваешь два значения с одинаковыми типами_ - то разницы нет какой оператор использовать

Comment: А уверен ты можешь быть только в `TypeScript` :)

Comment: в TypeScript ты тоже не можешь быть уверен

Comment: Ну если использовать `any` на каждом шагу то конечно:))

Answer (score -1):

> Где целесообразно использовать сравнение через ===?

Везде. (и всегда)

Comment: За деталями можно сходить, например, сюда http://2ality.com/2011/12/strict-equality-exemptions.html

Comment: В место ссылки можно было бы и самому более развернутый ответ нписать